# Order an hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got an hash that looks like this

`{"1-5 lbs"=>107342.43999999999, "31+ lbs"=>39838.58000000001, "21-30 lbs"=>19036.41, "11-20 lbs"=>39350.95, "6-10 lbs"=>41401.880000000005}`

And I'd like to sort it so it looks like this

`{"1-5 lbs"=>107342.43999999999, "6-10 lbs"=>41401.880000000005, "11-20 lbs"=>39350.95, "21-30 lbs"=>19036.41, "31+ lbs"=>39838.58000000001 }`

The logic is being stored in an instance variable `@weight_ranges`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to get into regular expressions to get the value of the first number of each
range.

```
Hash[(@weight_ranges.sort_by {|key, value| key.scan(/\d+/)[0].to_i})]
```

To break it down further:

```
# Sort the weight ranges by the first series of digits found in the key
x = @weight_ranges.sort_by {|key, value| key.scan(/\d+/)[0].to_i}
# Convert each inner Array to a key, value pair in a Hash
x = Hash[x]
```

Comment: Actually you can get away without regexes here.

Answer (score 2):

You depicted the data as a hash.  For a sequence you'll need an array of pairs.  Something like this will do it:

```
list_of_pairs = @weight_ranges.keys.sort_by(&:to_i).map {|k| [k, @weight_ranges[k]]}
```

This exploits a happy coincidence that `to_i` stops at the first non-digit it sees.

**Correction**

I have just learned that in 1.9 Ruby hashes are ordered!  So it's easy to adapt:

```
Hash[@weight_ranges.sort_by{|k,v| k.to_i}]
```

I'll leave both ideas here, since the first one is still right for Ruby < 1.9.

Comment: One note - the first example actually returns an Array, not a Hash, which I think is what he's looking for. But wrapping it in Hash[] fixes that.

Comment: @acsmith  Right. I didn't realize until someone else posted that Ruby hashes are now ordered.  Before 1.9 they were not.  So I thought he'd need arrays to obtain a strict sequence. I'm not sure which method creates less garbage.  The `merge!` still needs a 1-key hash for its argument.  Probably should try simple assignment.